# creating list n copies of lists

Tags: python, list, copy

I need a list of lists, where entered the first two sublists manually, but the third until 5th list are copies of each other. How can I do the trick having to write the same list three times? This example does not what I want but instead produces a third sublist which is three times as long as I need it:

```
examplelist=[[1,2],[3,4],3*[5,6,7]]
>>>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7]]
```

I want:

```
>>>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: @sweeneyrod see my comment on mhawke's answer - that is not a good idea.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right, but to be fair the OP did not say whether it matters or not.

Comment: @mhawke the OP may well not know that it could be a problem. Multiple references to mutable objects is a pretty common Python "gotcha" that trips up a lot of new users and causes subtle bugs - your answer at least makes it clear that this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably best off doing this in a straightforward way:

```
l = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
l.extend([5, 6, 7] for _ in range(3))
```

If you multiply a list of lists (`[[5, 6, 7]] * 3 == [[5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]]`) you will end up with three references *to the same list*.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have other lists following the three identical lists....but your answer combined with pluses works fine! Thanks!

Comment: Facetiously, how much typing has this saved? Typing the full list: `len('l = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]]')` => 53 - versus len('l = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];l.extend([5, 6, 7] for _ in range(3))' => 58.

Comment: @mhawke very little, in this case! However, it reduces the risk of error (as you aren't writing out the same list multiple times) and scales better to changing `n`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways:

```
>>> [[1,2],[3,4]] + [[5,6,7]]*3
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]]
```

or

```
>>> examplelist=[[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> examplelist.extend([[5,6,7]]*3)
>>> examplelist
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]]
```

But note that the last 3 lists in the list will be the same:

```
>>> examplelist[-1][0] = 100
>>> examplelist
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [100, 6, 7], [100, 6, 7], [100, 6, 7]]
```

probably not what you want.

Comment: With either of these outputs, try `examplelist[2][1] = 9` and see where it gets you...

Comment: Thanks, already knew that was editing it... but your way seems better.

Answer (score 0):

Python will add lists to get what you expect:

```
>>> examplelist=[[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> n=3
>>> examplelist+=[[5,6,7] for i in range(n)]
>>> examplelist
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]]
```

You can also create the structure described in one go since expressions are evaluated as the list is constructed:

```
>>> li=[[1,2,3]] + [[5,6,7] for i in range(n)] + [[7,8,9]]
>>> li
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Note that your second version puts a list of lists at `li[1]`, they aren't in-line as the OP requests.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thanks! fixed. still wiping the sleep outta my eyes!

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> ex = [ [1,2], [3,4] ]
>>> ex.extend(repeat([5, 6, 7], 3))
>>> ex
>>> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: why voting this down when it gives the needed output?

Comment: This suffers from the same issue as @mhawke's answers - you get three references *to the same list object*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for that helpful hint, the three references actually change when only 1 item is altered. However I think their attempt is good enough.